# Scraping Information from Emails in Outlook - R

Tags: r, web-scraping, outlook

I receive emails multiple times a day that contain information that I'd like to compile in a spreadsheet. The format of the email appears as follows:

*Introductory Text*

**Field One**
Value One

**Field Two**
Value Two

etc. etc. etc. for 13 fields

I could of course copy and paste these fields into an Excel spreadsheet myself, but I'm hoping to automate the process with R. All emails are routed into their own folder in my Outlook and always come from the same email address. Is there any way I can do this, maybe with a script that I can run once a week to repopulate the spreadsheet?

Thanks in advance!

I tried something like this but couldn't replicate: http://apknight.org/sentiment-analysis-on-gmail-with-r-the-gmailr-package/

Comment: RDCOMClient can read outlook emails. It's not super easy to use though

Comment: depending on your subscription package {Microsoft365R} might have something useful (no own experience though): https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R

Comment: Have you considered using VBA in Excel to perform this task?  I believe I used stack overflow to find a script that did the trick.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dave2e, I think your solution will work best for me but thank you all!